# Adding Lists Together

Tags: list-manipulation

This is something that should be simple, but the documentation and other questions don't seem to deal with it. I can think of mechanically doing it through a loop, but I know there must be a better way.

In this example, I have three lists (although the actual operation will involve several sets of 20-30 each, and they're much longer):

```
list1={1,5,5,5,5,6};
list2={2,1,2,2,2,2};
list3={3,3,3,3,3,3};
```

What I need to do is add them together - as in all the first positions of the three lists being added together, all the second positions, and all the third positions, so that I just have say:

```
list4={6,9,10,10,10,11};
```

The actual order of the list is important (I'm using it to store data). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is another approach (much better) - `Total` :

```
Total[{list1, list2, list3}]
```

> ```
> {6, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11}
> ```

or `Apply` the function `Plus` :

```
Plus @@ {list1, list2, list3}
```

or

```
MapThread[ Plus, {list1, list2, list3}]
```

Comment: Interesting.  Total and Plus @@ are about 50% faster than list1 + list2 + list3 (they are the same speed as each other).  I wonder why.  The truly odd thing is that MapThread is more than two orders of magnitude slower!

Comment: @MarkAdler Are you sure you aren't micro-optimizing and looking at negligible differences on tiny lists? I can't imagine `Plus@@` being faster, as `Apply` unpacks the list...

Comment: @MarkAdler It depends on the data you are deal with, in general `Total` is faster than other approaches, nevertheless if we deal with unpacked lists, `Plus` would be faster.

Comment: @Artes, I prefer your answer to mine.

Comment: @yulinlinyu Your answer is straightforward when you deal with small lists, however for long lists mine should be faster.

Comment: I did the test on lists with one million numerical entries.  Plus@@ and Total took almost exactly the same amount of time as each other.  They were packed arrays.

Comment: I had done those tests using vectors generated using RandomInteger[].  I repeated the tests using RandomReal[].  In that case, there was no longer any difference between list1 + list2 + list3 and Total/Plus@@.  All three had very close times.  Still, MapThread came out almost two orders of magnitude slower.  (Also using packed arrays.)

Comment: There is also `Tr /@ Transpose[{list1, list2, list3}]`, seemingly quite fast for packed arrays, see [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_31.html) (Ted Ersek) and [here](http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Software/Mathematica/Tutorials/TipsTricks/FastAdd.html) (Paul Abbott)

Comment: Wow, no.  Tr/@Transpose was about the same speed as the MapThread above, which is two orders of magnitude slower than the other solutions.  (Again, this was on packed arrays of integers and reals, one million in length.)

Comment: In summary, the obvious solution of list1 + list2 + list3 on packed arrays of reals is just as fast as the other fastest solutions (so far) of Total[{list1,list2,list3}] or Plus@@{list1,list2,list3}.  So the "much better" claim in this answer is not borne out, at least in terms of speed.  (The assertion in a comment above about Apply always unpacking is also apparently not true.)  The MapThread and Tr/@Transpose solutions are two orders of magnitude slower.  (I am using Mma 8.0.4.0 on an Intel Core 2 Duo, Mac OS X.)

Comment: @MarkAdler It is in fact better if you test more extensively varoius types of lists, not restricting to this problem literally. You can use it in more general situations, then it apears to be better (not always). Look at the documentation center to read `Total` and try more examples to compare with `Plus`. Consider also comparing it with `Plus@@@list[list1,list2,...,listn]`.

Comment: Why should I compare it with something that gives the wrong result?

Comment: @MarkAdler It doesn't yield wrong results, it serves different purpose. `(Plus @@@ {list1,list2,...,list2})==( Total /@{list1,list2,...,list2})`

Comment: I know what it does -- it's trivial to see by inspection.  My point is that there is no conceivable reason to do a speed comparison between two things that produce different output or take different input.  For this question, the comparison has to be with list1 + list2 + list3.

Answer (score 19):

Do you mean `list4 = list1 + list2 + list3`  ?

```
(* {6, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11} *)
```

Comment: Oh my god. This is embarrassing. I've been reading through the List documentation for ages, when this was right in front of me.

Comment: I'm happy to close as long as you get your rep..

Comment: @ian.milligan It might be embarrassing, but it's not a bad question and it may help future visitors.

Answer (score 6):

This is complementary to the other answers — since you say that you have 20-30 lists that need to be added, you can't be entering them all by hand. Here's a way to build up the lists you want to add:

```
ToExpression@StringJoin @@ Riffle["list" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[10], "+"]
(* list1+list2+list3+list4+list5+list6+list7+list8+list9+list10 *)
```

Comment: I think that if there are 20-30 lists, then storing them in separate variables (not an indexed variable or array) is a plain bad idea to start with, which I would not encourage. But apart from that, using string manipulations I view as a last resort, since they are error-prone. It is always better to work with already parsed code, and if you can't, it usually indicates (to me at least) that something is wrong with the data representation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I agree and I wouldn't do it this way, but apparently it looks like the OP has things set up this way, hence the question...