# How to Update 2D List based on a binary array

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

I have 3 lists:

```
numbers = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
toUpdate = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}};
newValues = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50,60}};
```

I have to update the list `numbers` such that, if the value in an a particular index `{i,j}` in `toUpdate` is `1`, then the value in `newValues` is copied to numbers.

i.e. for the above example the final result should be,

```
number = {{10, 2}, {3, 4}, {50, 60}};
```

In the `toUpdate` list there will be 50% of 0s and 50% of 1s.

So far the best way I know is to use `Rule` or to use `Do[]`. I am skeptical of using both of these methods because,

- `Rule` creates a new list and has to copy all the numbers.
- With `Do[]` I can update in place, but results in a larger piece of code and I want to eliminate it.

**PS:** Is there a way to **update in place** if there is a function instead of `toUpdate` list?

Comment: All Answers are better, but I am going to accept that of @kguler, because it modifies the original list itself, the way I want.

Comment: It seems your view how _Mathematica_ works is wrong. You  can check what names are created with e.g. `Names["Global'*"]` (apostrophe after `Global`).  If you are to modify the original list you can do: `numbers = numbers Abs[toUpdate - 1] + toUpdate newValues;`. Of course my solution is simply the best but I wouldn't like to change your choice.

Comment: @Artes, Sorry I am new to Mathematica, I am a .Net developer by profession. To my knowledge, creating a completely new list and to fill it, instead of changing a few values is not optimal. I have worked with Matlab before, and there is a way to update specific elements in a list based on a matrix or a function. I want a similar optimal solution, because I will be doing this operation around a million times in one go and it takes more than a minute for the complete execution.

Comment: As you said there are 50%  `0`'s and `1`'s so if you work with sufficiently long lists there is no way to outperform basic `Plus` and `Times` operations, therefore I have said it is the best way. And of course when you gain some experience with _Mathematica_ you'll see how it is different than standard compilable programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(numbers[[##]]=newValues[[##]])&@@@Position[toUpdate,1]; (* thanks: Karsten7 *)
numbers
(*  {{10,2},{3,4},{50,60}}  *)
```

Comment: Or `(numbers[[##]] = newValues[[##]]) & @@@ Position[toUpdate, 1];`

Answer (score 5):

You might use `Position`

`pos = Position[toUpdate, 1]` obtains, from `toUpdate`,  the positions that you need to update and stores them in `pos`.

`Extract[newValues, pos]` finds the values to be inserted.  They are at the same positions in the list, `newValues`.

`ReplacePart` inserts those values in the proper places--same positions, once again--in `numbers`.

```
pos = Position[toUpdate, 1]
ReplacePart[numbers, Thread[pos -> Extract[newValues, pos]]]
```

> {{10, 2}, {3, 4}, {50, 60}}

Answer (score 4):

Because of lisatability of `Iimes`, `Plus`  and `Abs` (see the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute and examine the full form of the underlying expression, moreover take a look at a fine structure of list addition in *Mathematica* e.g. [Adding Lists Together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/adding-lists-together)) one can do simply this:

```
numbers Abs[toUpdate - 1] + toUpdate newValues
```

> ```
> {{10, 2}, {3, 4}, {50, 60}}
> ```

This solution exploits a **specific form**  of `toUpdate` list and most likely it should be the **fastest one** however in more general cases there is a vast space of possible operations on lists. See also the structure of the above operation using `Inactive` (new in *Mathematica 10*):

```
FullForm[ Inactive[ numbers Abs[toUpdate - 1] + toUpdate newValues]]
```

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thanks, I like your approach as well (+1) since it can be easily generalized.